# separate <td> exact data to <tags>

Tags: javascript, html, datatable, html-table

I'm parsing HTML and want to get only data from table's  elements. But my current code displays more than I want it to, including  tags etc. please check the screenshot for more clear view.
[Screenshot Of Table Here please](https://screenshots.firefox.com/lrEVoogV0XPM2ZCL/localhost)

[Output of my current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQr4K.jpg)

***As you can see in second screenshot it displays me this all with tags. SSL RenewalsX*** i just want to get SSL Renewals

I want to separate data from all tags available in data variable.

HTML:

```
<table id="items">

      <tr>
          <th>Item</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Unit Cost</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Price</th>
      </tr>

      <tr class="item-row">
          <td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea name="invoice_item">Web Updates</textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div></td>
          <td class="description"><textarea name ="description[]">Monthly web updates for http://widgetcorp.com (Nov. 1 - Nov. 30, 2009)</textarea></td>
          <td><textarea class="cost">$650.00</textarea></td>
          <td><textarea class="qty">1</textarea></td>
          <td><span class="price">$650.00</span></td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="item-row">
          <td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea>SSL Renewals</textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div></td>
          <td class="description"><textarea>Yearly renewals of SSL certificates on main domain and several subdomains</textarea></td>
          <td><textarea class="cost">$75.00</textarea></td>
          <td><textarea class="qty">3</textarea></td>
          <td><span class="price">$225.00</span></td>
      </tr>

      <tr id="hiderow">
        <td colspan="5"><a id="addrow" href="javascript:;" title="Add a row">Add a row</a></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
          <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
          <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Subtotal</td>
          <td class="total-value"><div id="subtotal">$875.00</div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>

          <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
          <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Total</td>
          <td class="total-value"><div id="total">$875.00</div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
          <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Amount Paid</td>

          <td class="total-value"><textarea id="paid">$0.00</textarea></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
          <td colspan="2" class="total-line balance">Balance Due</td>
          <td class="total-value balance"><div class="due">$875.00</div></td>
      </tr>

    </table>
    <input  onclick="myFunction()" type="submit" name="save" value="Save">
```

SCRIPT:

```
<script>

    function myFunction(){

        //gets table
        var oTable = document.getElementById('items');
        //gets rows of table
        var rowLength = oTable.rows.length;
        //loops through rows    
        for (i = 0; i < rowLength; i++){
            //gets cells of current row  
            var oCells = oTable.rows.item(i).cells;
            //gets amount of cells of current row
            var cellLength = oCells.length;

            //loops through each cell in current row
            for(var j = 0; j < cellLength; j++){
                // get your cell info here

                var cellVal = oCells.item(j).innerHTML;
                alert(cellVal);
           }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: all cells have separate structure some have the text like prices directly added into the cell some has the html containing a textarea inside a div from which you wan to get the desired text so what i would advise is to add a specific class to all those elements and then get the text inside it.

Comment: do you want to get the text from the form fields like `input` , `textarea` or html elements like `div` too?

Comment: i can get data from simple <td> tags , what is want is to get data from <textarea> like tags

Comment: see the answer i added below to collect the data from the textarea inputs with form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the textarea values like below if you donot have a form currently and you can also serialize the textarea values, if you like to see a demo below.

```js
function myFunction() {
  let queryString = '';
  var formFields = document.querySelectorAll('textarea');

  formFields.forEach(function(textarea) {

    //creates querystring for the form inputs
    queryString += textarea.name + '=' + textarea.value + '&';

    //show the value of the textarea
    console.log(textarea.value);
  });

  //remove the extra "&" from the end of the querystring
  queryString = queryString.substr(0, queryString.length - 1);

  console.log("==FOR USING AS QUERY STRING FOR====");
  console.log(queryString);

  //send ajax call to save the form data
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "your url.php",
    data: queryString,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      //var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data); if the dataType is not specified as json uncomment this
      // do what ever you want with the server response
    },
    error: function() {
      alert('error handing here');
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<table id="items">

  <tr>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Unit Cost</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>

  <tr class="item-row">
    <td class="item-name">
      <div class="delete-wpr"><textarea name="invoice_item[]">Web Updates</textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div>
    </td>
    <td class="description"><textarea name="description[]">Monthly web updates for http://widgetcorp.com (Nov. 1 - Nov. 30, 2009)</textarea></td>
    <td><textarea class="cost" name="unit_cost[]">$650.00</textarea></td>
    <td><textarea class="qty" name="quantity[]">1</textarea></td>
    <td><span class="price">$650.00</span></td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="item-row">
    <td class="item-name">
      <div class="delete-wpr"><textarea name="invoice_item[]">SSL Renewals</textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div>
    </td>
    <td class="description"><textarea name="description[]">Yearly renewals of SSL certificates on main domain and several subdomains</textarea></td>
    <td><textarea class="cost" name="unit_cost[]">$75.00</textarea></td>
    <td><textarea class="qty" name="quantity[]">3</textarea></td>
    <td><span class="price">$225.00</span></td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="hiderow">
    <td colspan="5"><a id="addrow" href="javascript:;" title="Add a row">Add a row</a></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
    <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Subtotal</td>
    <td class="total-value">
      <div id="subtotal">$875.00</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
    <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Total</td>
    <td class="total-value">
      <div id="total">$875.00</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
    <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Amount Paid</td>

    <td class="total-value"><textarea id="paid">$0.00</textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
    <td colspan="2" class="total-line balance">Balance Due</td>
    <td class="total-value balance">
      <div class="due">$875.00</div>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
<input onclick="myFunction()" type="submit" name="save" value="Save">
```

Comment: Thanks for answer , i really appreciate this

Comment: you are welcome @user9991765 , is this all you wanted to do , will it solve the problem

Comment: can you do me a one favor , i want to save this whole data in php variable or array so that i can store it in MySQL

Comment: sure feel free @user9991765

Comment: ok and how are you sending html call, using jquery or javascript ? @user9991765

Comment: this whole table is inside <form with method=get> i am getting all variables one by one and sending them in pdo query , but now i have all the data in javascript variable ,so i want to convert this javascript variable to php array or something so that i can send data to pdo . what do you think ? https://pastebin.com/C3ukNBTs

Comment: @user9991765 you can use ajax request, to send the data to your php file , which does the same work as a form submit do sends data to your server using post or get request which ever you want , you need to decide if you are going to use jquery for the ajax request orsimple javascript, that depends on what your requirements are

Comment: @user9991765 you are welcome, do mark the answer as correct by clicking the ✓ icon

Comment: how can i get values of unnamed

Comment: how can i get values of unnamed textarea , newly created rows ? thanks

Comment: you can still get the textareas that even have no names but it is not a good approach to add any input with name or id , as you need to specify a label for every input when creating a querystring and adding an attribute helps building it @user9991765

Comment: i am just stuck in this project , can you please help me out , i will be really thankful to you... can you please write script to traverse through querystring to separate all fields or something that will help me . please

Comment: i just want to save all table data to database from all fields of table

Comment: yes you can  an i already have provided the script for doing that you need to provide the `name` attribute at least  on all the `textarea` fields, i even added an ajax call, to send the data if you see above

Comment: https://pastebin.com/TUHHWYZA this is my script , i don't know how it is adding rows ?

Comment: your Pastebin does not have the function `bind()`

Comment: https://files.fm/u/y7f39ax3 i don't know what the heck is wrong with this code , here is complete files i have

Answer (score 0):

You can use the innerText property, this will work regardless of how many childNodes your td elements have: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp

```
<script>

    function myFunction(){

        //gets table
        var oTable = document.getElementById('items');
        //gets rows of table
        var rowLength = oTable.rows.length;
        //loops through rows    
        for (i = 0; i < rowLength; i++){
            //gets cells of current row  
            var oCells = oTable.rows.item(i).cells;
            //gets amount of cells of current row
            var cellLength = oCells.length;

            //loops through each cell in current row
            for(var j = 0; j < cellLength; j++){
                // get your cell info here

                var cellVal = oCells.item(j).innerText;
                alert(cellVal);
           }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: thanks for answer textContent works for me. i am still getting X on first cell of <tr>